# Laravel 5.5 - Only log 500 error, never send error details via api?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, api-design, laravel-5.5, laravel-response

I made the below controller to demonstrate the issue of handling 500 errors I am having with the api. I want to be able to detect when a 500 error will be thrown so it never makes it to the client (as it is too much details to share with the client and they should only be logged by Laravel).

The method`getUser()` returns a 500 error intentionally due to the typo `firsgt()`

```
class TestController extends Controller {
  public function getUser() {
    $data = User::firsgt(); //returns 500 error
    return $data;
  }
}
```

This is what the client sees:
[image]

How can we return an error message like 'Error occurred' instead of the too much details for client 'Call to undefined method App\User::firsgt()'?

Note: I don't want to handle it one by one for each controller method, but instead capture any 500 before it is returned to client, and return the custom 500 generic message 'Error occurred'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the variables in your `.env` file to prevent these messages from being sent with the response.

<s>APP_ENV=production</s>

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Edit: just setting `APP_DEBUG` to false is enough.

**Update:**
If you're using dingo api package, then beside setting `APP_DEBUG` to false you need to edit the config file.

If you haven't already done yet, publish dingo config file

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

Then, open config/api.php and edit the `errorFormat` value to whatever message you want.

Replace `:message` with a generic message

Comment: This works really well on standard laravel but I am having the issue using  dingo api. Marked as correct since it helps other and myself for the laravel solution (which I thought would solve my specific issue), but does not work when used with the dingo api. Will open a question for the dingo api version of the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You have `app/Exception/Handler.php` class to do this. For example you can use code similar to this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $exception_class = get_class($e);

    if (!in_array($exception_class, [ValidationException::class, ModelNotFoundException::class] ) {
       return response()->json(['info' => 'Error occurred'], 500);
    }

   return parent::render();
}
```

but as you see you should exclude some exception classes that you would like to be rendered in normal way, here are only some sample exception classes.

Obviously in case you are designing API probably there is no point to use `parent::render()` at all and you should handle custom exception classes in custom way and then finally for other exceptions just return 500 response with the message you want.

Comment: Thank you for this, I found for laravel, it was a lot easier to just do `APP_DEBUG = false` so it handles the errors safely/generically 'error occurred' for clients. The issue I have still stands but with dingo api, so I opened the same question but for dingo api.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try ... catch`

```
try{
   .....
}catch(\Exception $e){
  if($e->getCode() == 500){
      return response()->json(["error"=>'$e->getCode()'],500);
  }
}
```

Comment: true, but I didn't want to use try catch explicitly in my code for all controller methods. Just a simple global way to handle any 500 laravel throws and capture the error bubbling up.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel already does this for you, but only if you are in production mode and the request is expecting JSON.

Anyhow, the **App\Exceptions\Handler** class is where all exceptions can be handled. It's also the place where all exceptions are logged and rendered by Laravel itself.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // your logic here

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The detailed explanation of the error are shown in develpment environments, for production you don't want to show them -for security reasons- so, as @Hamoud stated, go to your `.ENV` file find the line:

```php
APP_DEBUG=true
```

change it to:

```php
APP_DEBUG=false
```

This will show only the standard error responses. Check the documentation about [error details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#error-detail).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the message data from the Laravel response, nativiely, you need to look for the response data, where the message is included.  This only works when APP_DEBUG=true, this should not be enabled in production, but for clarity:

Suppose you are using `axios` to make the request, it would look something like this:

```
axios.get("/api/catalogs/clients/")
                .then(res => {
                    this.client = res.data;
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    print(e.message); //This would print Server error
                    this.clientError = e.response.data.message; //This will print Call to undefined method
                });
```